# How to keep querying a table without multiple Ajax webservice call

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this SQL query which is used in the code below.

`SELECT STATUS FROM STATUS_CHECK WHERE uniqueuId = ?`

Different values of STATUS are `NOT STARTED`, `RUNNING`, `COMPLETE`, `ERROR`.

I need to keep checking the value of STATUS from time to time and do some operations as soon as I find `COMPLETE` and wondering what approach I should following to achieve my task. Any ideas in which direction I could proceed?

Right now, in the code below, I only see `NOT STARTED` and my code exits.And I am not sure how to check the status without calling the webservice again after sometime to make sure that it changed to `COMPLETE` so that I could do some operations on it.

Let's say I have the following controller,DAO and DAoImple to get the `STATUS`

**Controller:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/statusCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void statusCheck
     (
     @RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "") String id

    ) {
    try {
       StatusDao sDao = (StatusDao) context.getBean("sDao");
       sDao.statusLookUp(id);
    } catch (Throwable th) {th.printStackTrace();}
   }
```

**Data Access Object(DAO):**

```
public interface StatusDao {
    void statusLookUp(String id) throws DaoException;
}
```

**DAO Impl:**

```
public class StatusDaoImpl implements StatusDao {

     public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
      jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
     }


     @Override
     public void statusLookUp(String id) throws DaoException {

      DataSource ds = null;
      Connection conn = null;
      PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
      CallableStatement cStmt = null;
      ResultSet rs = null;

      try {
       ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
       conn = ds.getConnection();
       cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call STATUS_RETRIEVER.GET_STATUS(?)}");
       cStmt.setString(1, id);
       cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);

       int uniqueId = cStmt.getInt(2);

       pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT STATUS FROM STATUS_CHECK WHERE uniqueuId=?");
       pstmt.setInt(1, uniqueId);
       rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
       rs.next();

       String status = rs.getString("STATUS");
       System.out.println("The status received is as follows:");
       System.out.println(status);

      } catch (Throwable th) {
       throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
      }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try scheduling to task to run every second or even in milliseconds, as per your need.
J2EE and Spring Framework Both provide Job Scheduling Feature.
You can schedule the task with a fixed time delay, or Schedule Task using Cron Expressions.
Check here.

[J2EE Scheduling](https://www.baeldung.com/scheduling-in-java-enterprise-edition)

Comment: You mean, this this line `String status = rs.getString("STATUS");` can be scheduled? And if I do that, let's say I have another Ajax call that comes in, which would need another scheduling for the same task, is it going to work in that case? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can schedule the whole method. I did not get the AJAX call scenario. Please provide some explaination

Comment: The problem with scheduling the whole method is that it will generate a new `uniqueId` which is coming out from the `OUT` parameter of the stored procedure call `cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);`. Hence, I am wondering if something can be done on this specific line `String status = rs.getString("STATUS");` because the uniqueId won't change at this line.

Comment: Ajax call scenario : If I send 1st Ajax request, it will call the stored procedure which generates `uniqueId` and based on this ID, I am checking the status. If I send another Ajax call, a new `uniqueId` will be generated and I would have to check the status based on that. Let me know if something isn't clear. I'll elaborate more if something is not clear to you. Thanks

Comment: You can run this line in a loop and have the thread in sleep mode for a short duration, if that doesn't harm your entire project as it will not be a good practice

Comment: Do you think JMS Queue could be used in this scenario? I can use ApacheMQ MOM.

Comment: John i have never tried JMS Queue or ApacheMQ before. Please tell the operation you want to perform as soon as the STATUS is COMPLETE are only server-side or do you have to respond back?

Comment: Ok. Once I get the `STATUS` as `COMPLETE`, I want to run select queries (based on the same `uniqueId` that I used to check the status) on 3-4 different tables , grab the data, convert it into CSV and put it somewhere on the server. I didn't mention about it since my first hurdle is to figure out how to reach `COMPLETE` status.

Comment: I understand your situation.
What you can do is create a list of each `UniqueId` you receive in `AJAX`.
Create a Scheduled method that periodically takes IDs from this list and check the database the status of each ID, as soon as the `STATUS` of an ID is changed to `COMPLETE`, perform your Operation (to CSV thing) and remove this `UniqueID` from list as well

Comment: Hmm. In that scenario, let's say first Id is currently being processed by the scheduled method and in the mean while, second Ajax request comes in, generates a new ID, is that scheduled method not going to take this new ID until it finishes its first task?

Comment: you are right, the scheduled method will only look for that new id when it runs next time.

Comment: Yeah, in that scenario, if it's going to take hours for the status to change to COMPLETE, I would get stuck. :(